# PHP __DIR__ Down folder "ROOT PATH"

Tags: php, path, root, dir

/home/dev/109/websits/htdocs/proyect/config/index.php
when I "echo **DIR**" give me a path 
"/home/dev/109/websits/htdocs/proyect/config/" but I want to download a folder

but I do not know if the project folder or another name will be called

"/home/dev/109/websits/htdocs/another/config/" etc..

I want everything to end in the following path

/home/dev/109/websits/htdocs/another/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please clarify a little bit more, what you actually want to achieve. Saying so, dirname(__FILE__) might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry my bad explanation, which is that when I try echo __DIR__
and returns me "/home/dev/109/websits/htdocs/another/config/"
change path "/home/dev/109/websits/htdocs/another/"

Comment: please try dirname(dirname(\__FILE__))